# Half triangle in css with border radius

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have this code of a half triangle with css but I need to put it a border radius at the midpoint of the triangle, like the image:

```
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0px 30px 20px 0;
border-color: transparent #bde5ff transparent transparent;
border-top-left-radius: 2px;
```

[image]

Any idea ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve that effect with a combination of [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) and [`transform: skew()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) on your triangle element. With skewing the element, the border radius effect remains on the corner.

Here is a working single element example. Adjust the respective values to your needs.

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  background: lightblue;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
div::before {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top: 20px;
  content: "";
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: lightblue;
  transform: skew(50deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```